# CORDA node configuration in Azure

Tags: azure, corda

Have deployed the cordapp in Azure and could see the party names as default names like organization 0, organization 1 etc..But I need to update the participant identities according to the requirement. Can anyone let me know where to change it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Comment: Which instructions did you follow to deploy the network to Azure?

Comment: Followed https://docs.corda.net/azure-vm.html.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you give a try on our latest version of the bootstrapper: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/network-bootstrapper.html

With the new network bootstrapper, you would actually define the names for the nodes in the mock network prior to deployment.

The exact steps are listed in this question: [ByteSequence not on whitelist or annotated @CordaSerializable issue while adding new node using network bootstrapper 4.0 OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59896554/bytesequence-not-on-whitelist-or-annotated-cordaserializable-issue-while-adding/62311768#62311768)