# ByteSequence not on whitelist or annotated @CordaSerializable issue while adding new node using network bootstrapper 4.0 OS

Tags: corda

**I am trying to add new node to existing corda network**

ByteSequence is not on the whitelist or annotated with @CordaSerializable issue while adding new node using corda network  bootstrapper 4.0 open source

To add a new node to an existing network I followed below option which is recommended here at this link 
[How to add a new node to an existing corda network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59497006/how-to-add-a-new-node-to-an-existing-corda-network)

I Used the network bootstrapper https://docs.corda.net/network-bootstrapper.html (and followed docs correctly)

I am getting below error when running

`java -jar corda-tools-network-bootstrapper-4.0.jar  --dir <nodes-root-dir>` command.

Error :-

```
Loading existing network parameters... [ERROR] 14:57:27+0530 [main] amqp.DeserializationInput.log - Serialization failed direction="Deserialize", 
type="java.lang.Comparable<net.corda.core.utilities.ByteSequence>", 
msg="Class "java.lang.Comparable<net.corda.core.utilities.ByteSequence>" is not on the whitelist or annotated with @CordaSerializable.", 
ClassChain="java.lang.Comparable<net.corda.core.utilities.ByteSequence>"
Class "java.lang.Comparable<net.corda.core.utilities.ByteSequence>" is not on the whitelist or annotated with @CordaSerializable
```

**Results after running this command :-**

1. New node's folder got created and node-info file got copied at appropriate places to other nodes as well.
2. Got the above error on command line when executed the above java command.
3. New Node got up and running when tried java -jar corda.jar on new node.
4. But existing node-info files from "additional-node-infos" folder of other nodes got updated with some content related to this serialization in it.

Please help on below

1. To resolve this error regarding  Corda Serialization when running bootstrapper command ?
2. Regarding Point no. 04 from above is this a correct behavior ?

Comment: Do you have a flow that starts on node startup (i.e. called by a Corda service), and that flow uses `ByteSequence`?

Comment: No  and i am NOT using ByteSequence anywhere in my corda code explicitly. please help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you cannot even successfully bootstrapped the network. I would suggest you give a try on our latest version of the boot-strapper:https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/network-bootstrapper.html

The primary reason people use boot-strapter is to start a mock network remotely. Ideally, you would go through the following steps:

1. build your cordapp
2. use deployNodes to get the directories for each nodes.
3. copy the XXX_node.conf file to a different folder
4. make change to your node.conf to update any changes for ports or etc
5. copy the CorDapps jars to the new folder
6. run the bootstrapper
7. copy the newly generated directories to the remote vm.